# How to remove lines connect dots and surface layers in R "scatter3d"?

Tags: r, scatter3d

I used scatter3d to create a plot below:
[image]
Here is my codes:

```
scatter3d(x, y, z, groups = db$Tumor_biology_code,
          surface=TRUE, grid = FALSE, ellipsoid = FALSE,
          surface.col = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9"),
          id = db$number,
          xlab = "HToriginal_shape_SurfaceVolumeRatio",
          ylab = "HToriginal_glcm_Correlation",
          zlab = "HToriginal_gldm_DependenceNonUniformityNormalized")
```

Can anyone knows how to remove these lines that connect dots and the yellow or blue surface lyaers?

I tried to change arguments of scatter3d like
"neg.res.col", "pos.res.col", "grid.lines"
but not work

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?